# Is plausible positive or negative?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

When *plausible* means "appear to be correct" or "superficially pleasing", I want to know if it is positive or negative because this decides which of the following is correct.

1. Conclusions of the theory are plausible and inexact.
2. Conclusions of the theory are plausible but inexact.

Comment: What is the whole sentence this phrase is a part of?

Comment: I would view it with a positive connotation. So sentence two feel the best to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sentence two would be the better option. You are using the word *plausible* to mean "likely correct", "probable", or "reasonable". That your conclusions have a good chance of being correct is a positive thing, whereas the fact they are "inexact" is negative. To paraphrase, you seem to be saying: "These conclusions seem reasonable and have a good chance of being correct, *but* we cannot be exact in proving/defining them."